# Simple device for 24 fast rising/falling edge detection

Tags: digital-logic, daq

We have an assembly with 24 switches and contacts that is going to a 6 hours shock and vibration test.
We need to be sure none of them change state while they wiggle vigorously.
With commons DAQ devices, if i set the sampling rate to 1000, which is ok to intercept something, i can only log around 10-20 minutes.
Is there a device that i could configure to log differences in states, only triggered by a difference from initial state or triggered by any of them 24 inputs?

Thank you.

Comment: log time only when state changes

Comment: Are the switches allowed to be rewired for the test?

Comment: @Andyaka That would sort of defeat the test.

Comment: You need to give us a lot more information before we can give any answer.  For example: How are you planning to monitor switches contacts?  What are the relation between switches / contacts.  Sample schematic.  *sampling rate to 1000*, 1000 whats?